# ValueError in list-comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm calculating distance from center by

`dist = [sqrt(p*p + q*q) for p, q in (x, y)]`

But, getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

x & y are lists with x, y coordinate values.

Comment: You need to `zip(x, y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dist = [sqrt(p*p + q*q) for p, q in zip(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is a good fit for this:

```
>>> list(map(lambda p,q:sqrt(p*p + q*q), x, y))
[4.123105625617661, 5.385164807134504, 6.708203932499369]
```